# where V is a compelx inner product space prove that are selfadjoint?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, inner-products

Let $\alpha \in End(V)$ where V is a complex inner product space. Define $$\alpha_1 = \frac{1}{2}(\alpha+\alpha^*)\\ 
and \\
 \alpha_2 = \frac{1}{2i}(\alpha - \alpha^*)$$

(a) Prove that $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are selfadjoint and that $\alpha = \alpha_1+i\alpha_2$.

(b) Suppose also that $\alpha = \beta_1 + i\beta_2$ where $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ are selfadjoint. Prove that $\beta_1 = \alpha_1$ and $\beta_2 = \alpha_2$

(c) Prove that $\alpha$ is normal if and only if $\alpha_1 \alpha_2 = \alpha_2 \alpha_1$

So from the definition of selfadjoint, $\alpha \in End(V)$ is selfadjoint if and only if $\alpha$ = $\alpha^*$. How would I start by showing that $\alpha_1$ and  $\alpha_2$ are selfadjoint and then showing that $\alpha = \alpha_1+i\alpha_2$.

Okay with the help from the comments I was able to do parts (a) and (b).

Now I am only left to prove (c).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\alpha_1=\frac{1}{2}(\alpha+\alpha^*)$$
Then $$\alpha_1^*=\frac{1}{2}(\alpha^*+(\alpha^*)^*)=\frac{1}{2}(\alpha^*+\alpha)=\alpha_1$$
You can do the same for $\alpha_2$. For the rest, just multiply $\alpha_2$ by $i$, and then add $\alpha_1$

Comment: so im trying to do what you said for  $\alpha_2 = \frac{1}{2i}(\alpha - \alpha^*)$ however the difference on the inside is messing it up? could it be a typo on the problem?

Comment: when im calculating $\alpha_{2}^{*}$

Comment: $\alpha_{2}^{\ast}=(-i/2)^{\ast}(\alpha^{\ast}-(\alpha^{\ast})^{\ast})=(i/2)(\alpha^{\ast}-\alpha)=(-i/2)(\alpha-\alpha^{\ast})=(1/(2i))(\alpha-\alpha^{2})=\alpha_{2}$.

Comment: okay so for part (b), i have $\alpha$ = $\beta_1$ + $i\beta_2$ and $\beta_1$ = $\alpha$ - $i\beta_2$ and $\beta_{1}^{*}$ = $\alpha^{*}$ - $(i\beta_{2}^){*}$ how do I treat or simplify the $(i\beta_{2})^{*}$

Comment: i understand now thank you. the conjugate of $i$ is $-i$...so $i^{*}$ = $-i$.......thanks again

Comment: any help on part(c)?

Comment: What is the definition of "normal"? By explicitly writing $\alpha_1\alpha_2=\alpha_2\alpha_1$  you get $\alpha\alpha^*=\alpha^*\alpha$

Comment: im not understanding could you please elaborate...im trying to substitute what I have for $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ and show that the commute is equal

Comment: What is the definition of "normal"?

Comment: an endomorphism is normal if and only if $\alpha$$\alpha^{∗}$ exists and satisfies $\alpha^{∗}$$\alpha$ = $\alpha$$\alpha^{∗}$

Comment: $\alpha_1\alpha_2=\frac{1}{4i}(\alpha+\alpha^*)(\alpha-alpha^*)=\frac{1}{4i}(\alpha^2+\alpha^*\alpha-\alpha\alpha^*-\alpha^*2)$. Similarly $\alpha_2\alpha_1=\frac{1}{4i}(\alpha^2-\alpha^*\alpha+\alpha\alpha^*-\alpha^*2)$. Therefore $\alpha^*\alpha-\alpha\alpha^*=-\alpha^*\alpha+\alpha\alpha^*$. Group on one side $\alpha\alpha^*$, and on the other side $\alpha^*\alpha$

Comment: ok the trouble im really having trouble with is the other way

Comment: You still write equations for $\alpha_1\alpha_2$ and $\alpha_2\alpha_1$. If $\alpha\alpha^*=\alpha^*\alpha$, both become equal to $\frac{1}{4i}(\alpha^2-\alpha^{*2})$, so they are equal

Answer (score 0):

Some facts you need to prove first: $(cA)^{\ast}=c^{\ast}A^{\ast}$, $c^{\ast}$ is the complex conjugate of $c$, $(A^{\ast})^{\ast}=A$, $(A+B)^{\ast}=A^{\ast}+B^{\ast}$.